# SQL Function to loop through table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, loops, t-sql

I'm new to tSQL functions and I'm trying to do the following:

I have a table like this called Projects:

```
+----------+--------------+
| Code     | Previous_Code|
+----------+--------------+
| 001      | NULL         |
| 002      | 001          |
| 003      | 002          |
| 004      | NULL         |
| 005      | NULL         |
+----------+--------------+
```

And I'd like to create an SQL function to produce the following query result:

```
+----------+--------------+
| Code     | Original_Code|
+----------+--------------+
| 001      | 001          |
| 002      | 001          |
| 003      | 001          |
| 004      | 004          |
| 005      | 005          |
+----------+--------------+
```

I've come up with the function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION OriginalProjectCode (@Code VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Code2 AS VARCHAR(3);
WHILE @Code IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Code2 = @Code;
        SET @Code = ('SELECT [Previous_Code] FROM 
        Projects WHERE [Code] = ' + @Code);
        SET @Code2 = @Code;
    END;
RETURN @Code2;
END;
```

But it just seems to be in an infinite loop when it is run. Doe anyone one have any ideas or a better way of achieving the same result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirements? From your second table it seems that you want to follow the chain of `Previous_Code` values until you reach a `Code` with a `Previous_Code` of `NULL`, is that right? So, `003 -> 002 -> 001 -> NULL`, therefore "003" has an `Original_Code` of "001". I'm not clear though why "001" has an `Original_Code` of "001", when "004" and "005" both have `Original_Code`s of  "NULL"

Comment: How does your code executed the SQL statement? I don't see any sp_execute command.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Scalar functions in SQL Server can perform awfully, and introducing a `WHILE` loop into one is a double disaster. What is your actual goal here? You would be far far better off using an inline table-value function.

Comment: daveydavedave is right to point that out. The example is edited according now. Thanks.

Comment: Lamu the goal is to return the original code for any one code. Thanks for the input I'll look into table-value functions.

Comment: Isn't this just a hierarchy? A recursive CTE should do it. There's plenty of examples on SO

Comment: @user2751145 note I specifically said inline table-value functions. Multi Line Table-value functions can/do perform poorly as well. Make sure you specifically look at inline table-value functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!!

```
    CREATE TABLE #Projects(Code VARCHAR(10),Previous_Code VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO #Projects
    SELECT '001',NULL  Union ALL
    SELECT '002','001' Union ALL
    SELECT '003','002' Union ALL
    SELECT '004',NULL  Union ALL
    SELECT '005',NULL 

    DECLARE @id varchar(10)='003'

    ;with cte
    AS
    (
         select code,code as Original_Code,ISNULL(Previous_Code,code)Previous_Code
           from #Projects
           union all
          select c.Code,p.code as Original_Code, p.Previous_Code
           from #Projects p
             join cte c on c.Previous_Code = p.code  

    )

    SELECT code,Original_Code
    from cte 
    WHERE
        1= ( CASE WHEN Previous_Code IS NULL AND code !=Original_Code then 1
            WHEN code=Original_Code and Original_Code=Previous_Code then 1
            ELSE 0 END)
    order by code,Previous_Code


    DROP TABLE #Projects
```

Comment: Genius! I adapted that and got it to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems simple `case` expression would work :

```
select t.*, (case when Previous_Code is not null 
                  then coalesce(lag(Previous_Code, 1) over (order by code), Previous_Code) 
                  else code
             end) as Original_Code
from table t;
```

Comment: This "works" for up to two levels but fails if, say, `004`s `Previous_Code` is `003`, which should presumably mean that that row gets assigned `001` as well, but this code assigns it `002`. I think they're looking for something that works more generally